# how to allow different lan to use squid proxy

Tags: squid

I have internet access at **eth0** - live IP

**LAN** is connected at eth1 with ip address **10.1.98.0/24**. which is working fine.

http_port is 3128.

My question is how to allow different ip range like **10.1.142.0/24** to use squid proxy server in **LAN** ?

Please help?

Comment: issue is solved with just one command


#route add -net 10.1.142.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself please add an answer to your question and mark it as accepted, so other users who have the same problem will fidn the solution easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i cant ping from either-way from windows to linux, i just need to add the other ip range to allow through route command as below

to check allowed ip range

```
#route
```

and to allow other ip range in lan issue following command

```
#route add -net 10.1.142.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 eth1
```